# USB board to move mouse not working on ubuntu but works on Windows

Tags: ubuntu

I have a [whiteboard](http://www.genee-india.com/interactive-whiteboards/genee-powerboard/) which is used to move mouse on a respective computer when connected through usb.

It works perfectly on Windows but shows no movement on Ubuntu machine.

I am following the instructions as mentioned in the answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75558/ubuntu-make-fails-with-no-such-file-or-directory-lib-modules-3-4-0-build/75584#75584  to install cp210x.

I am able to see it connected, but not movement.

```
autoroot@autoroot:~/src/linux-source-3.2.0/drivers/usb/serial$ lsusb
....
Bus 005 Device 013: ID 4623:011a
```

Comment: Having the device connected does not mean there is a driver loaded for it.

Comment: @Ali Yeah, I know that. I am having hard time finding the appropriate driver.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Use `usb-devices` tool to find driver in use. I bet you'll find out that it uses `usbhid` driver.